# How can I clear socket buffer in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, buffer

I have a question about socket programming.  I want to clear the socket buffer.
I tried the following code:

```
int ret_read = read(return_events[index].data.fd, recv_buffer, sizeof(recv_buffer));
if(-1 == ret_read)
{
    if(EAGAIN != errno)
    {
        printf("read data from %d error occured, errno=%d, %s.\n", return_events[index].data.fd, errno, strerror(errno));
        /**
        Tag-position, I know buffer is not empty. I wonder clear buffer in code position.The buffer is socket recv buffer, is not recv_buffer.
        */
    }
    continue;
}
```

I don't want to use `read()` again in Tag-position, becase I want to set the buffer to empty.  Though using `read()` in Tag-position, I think it may fail.

Is there anyone who can tell me another way except `read()` in Tag-position?

Comment: You want to clear it why? Do you mean you want to clear your own `recv_buffer`, or the socket receive buffer? What does 'Tag-position' mean? What makes you think a buffer is non-empty when you've just received an error from `recv()`?

Comment: I have a deja-vu. That same question was asked some hours/one day ago.

Comment: And that does not look like C++ code. Pick **one** language!

Comment: @EJP,I want to clear socket receive buffer, is not recv_buffer.

Comment: There is no way to clear the socket receive buffer other than by reading from it. You haven't answered my other three questions.

Comment: @EJP(1)For example, First, Read-error happen when I read data from fd-1, so socket receive buffer is not set to empty.Sencond, I want to read new data, but I will read old data and new data.
(2)Tag Position, It is only postion flag.
(3)I think it is not empty, read fail cause to socket receive buffer is not clearly.

Comment: @study_20160808 what is the difference between old data and new data? how should the computer know how much of the buffer to clear?

Comment: *Non sequitur*. It does not follow from a read error that the socket read buffer is non-empty, and in any case a read error other than EAGAIN means that the connection is hosed anyway, so you can never read any more data. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP,No EAGAIN is not only indicate connection problem.For example, recv_buffer pointer is invalid address for some reason.It will also fail read and errno is not EAGAIN.

Comment: 1) You did not provide a [mcve]. 2) You do not clearly state what you mean 3) You posted that same question some hours/days ago already. 4) `errno == EAGAIN` is only true of your file does not block (`O_NONBLOCK`). By default reads **are** blocking and you don't provide information which shows different.

Comment: 5) If `recv_buffer` has an invalid address, you invoke undefined behaviour -> all messed up, you are lost anyway. And even iff that is reported: it is not `EAGAIN` and your next iteration will use - what? The same (wrong) address.

Comment: @Olaf,I got it.Thank you.I should detailly describle my problem and add some complete example in later.Thank you!

Comment: @immibis,I should check received data.These data should be added to the beginning and end of the tag.

Comment: @study_20160808 An invalid read buffer pointer would be a programming bug that would be triggered on the first call, which could be long before any data has arrived, so it doesn't imply data in the receive buffer, and it will never succeed until the program is corrected, which is an even more fatal condition than a hosed connection.

Comment: @EJP,I understand it.Thank you.How should I end this problem?

Comment: @study_20160808 What is a tag? You are using this word "tag", but it is not a standard thing in socket programming, and you have not explained what it means.

Comment: @immibisI just use it to make a mark.You shouldn't care too much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not different from any other buffer

```
 bzero(recv_buffer, sizeof(recv_buffer));
```

Comment: Hmm, ok, after reading the question again, that might be one option. Anyway, you should not answer such unclear questions. Instead drop a comment aksing for details/clarification.

Comment: @Olaf since a socket is nothing but a file descriptor I had only one option left to which "buffer" he's talking about. Also please note that not everyone who ask questions here know all of the correct terminology to everything. Yes this question is a bit unclear but it might be due to lack of experience and exposure.

Comment: @LiadBen-Yehuda There are two possible buffers, even three: `recv_buffer`, the socket receive buffer, and maybe the socket send buffer.

Comment: I should have clarified, from the code I see one option. Either way my answer applies to any chunk of memory that needs to be zeroed out

Comment: @LiadBen-Yehuda: That's exactly what comments are for. And no, that does only apply to memory under application-control. None in the libraries, nor the OS.

Comment: @EJP,the buffer is socket recv buffer, is not recv_buffer.

Comment: @LiadBen-Yehuda From the code I saw three options, and the OP has just confirmed that your choice is wrong. And it doesn't apply to clearing the socket send buffer.

Comment: I feel like you're just trying to be right. Of course it wouldn't apply to anything under the application control... but we're not talking about it. This is exhausting.

Comment: @LiadBen-Yehuda Of course I'm trying to be right. So you are you. So is the OP. So is Olaf. So, I sincerely hope, is everybody here. The comment doesn't make any sense. I don't know what 'anything under the application control' means.

Comment: I dont' think Olaf is receiving commands. Do you mean 'comment'. And if it was directed at him you should have added @Olaf. And I don't know what 'follow through' means either. You're not making much sense.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks for routing the "command". Actually I don't react positive when being commanded, ask my parents and teachers;-) But I think I listen to reason. "under application control" meant memory which was allocated some way (static/dynamic/automatic) by the application or is accessible by the application. The socket buffers are clearly not, as they are "under OS control" (or library, depending on the implementation).

Comment: @Olaf,I got it.I can't clear socket receive buffer or socket send buffer in application level by myself code.I maybe check readable data.Thank you!